# Initialize and fill a two dimensional array with data from an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, arrays, ienumerable

I need fill a two dimensional array with some values that comes from an IEnumerable.

```
public void ReturnJson(IEnumerable<Domain.Revenue.Revenue> listRevenues)
{
    double[,] dateYearActual;

    foreach (var variable in listRevenues)
    {
        dateYearActual= new double[,]
        {
           {CalculateMiliseconds(variable.DateHourInsertData), variable.Value}
        };
    }

    // ...
}
```

I don't know but I think that exist a better approach to do that, and in my `var data1` I have the following error `variable dateYearActual might not be initialized before accessing.`

Whats the better approach to fill a two dimensional arrays with values that came from an IEnumerable?

Comment: @EugenePodskal this is the wrong approach, with the `new double[,]` it always will create a new array. I need a better approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var values = listRevenues
     .Select(x => new 
                  { 
                     Seconds = CalculateMiliseconds(x.DateHourInsertData), 
                     Value = x.Value 
                  }).ToList();

double[,] dateYearActual = new double[values.Count,2];

for(int i=0; i<values.Count; i++)
{ 
    dateYearActual[i,0] = values[i].Seconds;
    dateYearActual[i,1] = values[i].Value;
}
```

Perform a projection and put the values into a `List` to avoid multiple enumeration. Then create the array using values.`Count` as row count and use a for loop to set each element to corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

The error your seeing is caused by the fact that you *could* skip the `foreach` loop and then when you try to access `dateYearActual` at the end of your code it would be uninitialized (i.e. you never assigned a value to it).  To fix that error you can change

```
double[,] dateYearActual;
```

to

```
double[,] dateYearActual = new double[listRevenues.Length, 2];
```

Another problem with your code is that you're recreating `dateYearActual` when you make this call: `dateYearActual= new double[,] ...`.  Instead, you'll want to use an indexing `for` loop instead of `foreach`:

```
for (int i =0; i<listRevenues.Length]; i++)
{
  listRevenues[i,0] = CalculateMiliseconds(variable.DateHourInsertData);
  listRevenues[i,1] = variable.Value;
}
```